# Cannot log in to careers.stackoverflow.com

Tags: support, jobs

After following the usual `log in` link on the [StackOverflow Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) page, and inputting my openID, it simply drops me back at the homepage, still not logged in.

The first time I attempted to do this, it brought me to the normal myopenid page, with the e-mail and password login, but then did the same as before - redirected me to http://careers.stackoverflow.com.

#### EDIT:

Attempted to log out of SO and MSO, and still experiencing the same trouble - the problem persists.

Comment: What browser/OS are you on? And do you use the same openID to log in to SO / MSO without problems?

Comment: Windows XP, and Firefox 6, and yes - using the same openID for SO and MSO has worked fine for me so far.

Comment: Sorry, we haven't been able to reproduce this.  Can you log in with other OpenIDs?  I see several logins for your user in our logs, which might indicate that the login was processed but your browser didn't accept the cookie for some reason.

Comment: I'll try clearing cookies and check back here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After clearing cookies and active logins, I was able to successfully enter a myopenid address, and log in through that.

I immediately noticed the difference upon doing that, since the [StackOverflow Careers login page](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/users/login) showed the e-mail address / password column (the smaller one) on the left, instead of on the right, as I'm used to seeing.

Regardless, no amount of manually logging out of other SE sites or even out of myopenid fixed it, but clearing all cookies and active logins did.